# Child theme doesn't read template part file

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building my first child theme. My child theme is my active theme at the moment. So, I have a file under the parent theme which is at `wp-content/themes/mytheme/template-parts/ajax-mytick-list.php` and I copied it to `wp-content/themes/mytheme-child/template-parts/ajax-mytick-list.php` and edit it there. But the site is not showing the one that I edited under child theme. Cos if I edit the same file in parent theme, the result is reflected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Honestly, what's wrong with answering this kinda question? Why "-1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override page templates this way, but not other files. In this case, you'll need to override the according function ([guide](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623)) or hook into it with an action hook or filter.

More details according to your question below:
You'll need to find out where the template-parts file is getting included. Search the parent theme for something like

```
require get_template_directory() . '/template-parts/ajax-mytick-list.php';
```

If that call is in a template file, copy it to your child theme and change the call to

```
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/ajax-mytick-list.php';
```

If it's not in a page template, you'll need to dig deeper, but as every theme is different, it's impossible to say how exactly you'll get there.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I dont really understand. So, meaning my file ajax-mytick-list.php cannot be overridden although it's in template-parts? If so, how do I know what can and cannot be overridden in template-parts? I was not the coder for parent theme.

Comment: Some more hints in my answer now. But you won't get around naming your parent theme or more details if you want more helpful answers.

Comment: Thanks so much. I found out that it's called at wp-content/themes/mytheme/inc/shortcodes/ajax-events.php and it looks like a template with lots of HTML tags. So, do you mean I just change the call in ajax-events.php in the parent theme to "require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/template-parts/template-parts/ajax-mytick-list.php';" or should I copy ajax-events.php to my child and then only change to the above? Btw, must it be "/template-parts/template-parts/" twice?

Comment: Nmv, I got it and it's working. Thanks a bunch! But I'm still curious why you use '/template-parts/template-parts' twice.

Comment: That wasn't by intention, sorry. I typed template-parts and then copied the filename including the path from your post. I you change the call in the parent theme, it might get overwritten, so better identify the template that's calling it and copy that to the child, or override the calling function.